# Through which values does this sum iterate $\sum_{i_1,...,i_k = 1}^{n}D_{i_k}....D_{i_1}f(x+t\zeta)\zeta_{i_1}...\zeta_{i_k}$ mean?

Tags: summation, index-notation

What is the first summand, the second summand and so on? How many sumands are there. I am sorry if this question is too short. I hope you can still help me.

Comment: Look at some simple cases: for $k=2$ then its $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n D_j D_i f(x+t \xi)\xi_i \xi_j$ where I have put $i_1 = i$ and $i_2 = j$. Its $k$ sums, $k$ derivatives in front and $k$ factors in the end. Try to write down the formula for $k=3$ to see if you understand it.

Comment: @Winther Could you also say you look at all tuples $(i_1,....,i_k)$ where $i_1+....+i_k\geq k$, and $1\leq i_j\leq n,$ for all $1\leq j \leq n$

Comment: If you want to phrase it this way isn't it simpler to just say all tuples where $1\leq i_j \leq n$? There is no need for that inequality.